# How can I change the Google Analytics timezone?

Tags: google-analytics

All howto's I was able to find in the Internet is slightly (or even not slightly) different from the things I see in my real account. This things is also applicable to the official Google help pages (!).

Where's the right place of this setting?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Go to the Admin page (rightmost link on the top of the main page)
2. Under View (rightmost panel of 3) select View Settings.
3. Under Time zone country or territory, select your desired country and time zone settings.

Comment: No longer the correct answer : see https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/104964/78953

Answer (score 7):

I think this process has changed with an update of the Analytics Interface.

You can find the Timezone setting for each "View" of each "Property" under each "Account" you manage.

1. Go to the Admin page which is now the bottom option on the menu down the left hand side of the Main Page.
2. Then select the Account you need to manage.
3. Select the Property
4. Then select the View for which you want to set/change the Time Zone.
5. Next, click on "View Settings" (currently the top option in the View
   panel You'll then see a Timezone, Country or Territory setting, 4
   options down...

*Until the next time the interface is changed...*

Comment: Has the interface changed again? I cannot seem to proceed after step 3. I do not get the option to 'View for which you want to set/change the Time Zone'.